# Using node-imagemagick to 'crop' an image uploaded to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, imagemagick, node-imagemagick

I'm building functionality that allows users to upload an image, then crop it to a square (for profile pictures etc...)

Currently, the process works like this:

- User selects image from hd
- Image is uploaded to S3
- S3 Path is sent back to view, and image with jCrop is shown
- On submit button being clicked, my controller action gets the coords set above

Now I'd like to crop this image to the given coords (note- I'm using [lpatters fork of node-imagemagick](http://github.com/lpatters/node-imagemagick/) as it contains '[offset](https://github.com/lpatters/node-imagemagick/blob/98a83a54a1d9ec67584a4ffa891257d8950a0049/test-crop.js#L13)'

Unfortunately, .crop only accepts a path - which we don't have, since it's hosted on S3 at this point.

Is there any workaround?

I saw [tmp](http://github.com/raszi/node-tmp), but this may be a little overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using some of the other entry points such as "resize" that then allow you to provide the custom arguments? I'm using streams in this code: https://github.com/jeffwilcox/4th-cloud/blob/master/lib/webserver.js#L542